# how to access master page controls from an app code file

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, vb.net-2010, literals, bootstrapping

I am trying to bootstrap our intranet site and in the process i'm trying to create a framework of sorts to help other developers use the bootstrap tools more efficiently, w/o a lot of duplicated code.

One example are the alert boxes. My idea is to have a literal on the master page (before the content placeholder), and populate this literal w/ the necessarily alert information as needed from the content code-behind pages. Ideally I could store this, and other bootstrap calls, in our "Bootstrap.vb" app code class. However it seems getting the vb file to pick up on the literal is pretty hard.

This works in the content pages, code-behind.

```
    Sub WarningAlert(pText As String)
     Dim Alert As New Literal
     Alert = CType(Master.FindControl("litAlert"), Literal)
     Alert.Text = "TEST 123"
    End Sub
```

Can someone help with placing this in our vb file, or have another suggestion? Another way would perhaps be doing a custom control, which i tried briefly and my project blew up. I'm pretty sure there must be a better way than my literal option, but I just can't think of it.

I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the below:

In the masterpage you declare a property called **Scripts**. and on page load you do whatever is needed.

Then in your pages you set the property with the below line of code:

**CType(Me.Master, MasterPage).Scripts** = "YOUR WHATEVER GOES HERE"

Comment: So how can I control where these are placed on the page? I wouldn't still use the literal? Or would i?

Comment: What should the literal do? You can still have a literal on the page and on pageload you set the literals text.